# CodeSandbox: Display codeline in console

Tags: codesandbox

How can you display the line of codes in the console in Codesandbox?

I was searching in the settings but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're `console.log()`ing them, there's nothing else you need to do. Codesandbox will log whatever is inside a `console.log()` statement and show it to you in the console tab.

Your ad blocker may be the reason you don't see anything. Turn it off, or try running your sandbox in Chrome's Incognito mode (assuming you don't have an ad blocker enabled in Incognito mode.)

Comment: If you wanted to display lines of code to the console in some other way, could you please clarify what you meant?